# I have implemented the following code to upload image on S3 .

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After getting the image from gallery i am calling the following function and when i run the program it runs with no error but still i cant find the image in my S3 bucket.This is my Function

private void uploadImageToAWS() {

```
    final AsyncTask<String, String, String> _Task = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
        {

            if (CheckNetStatus())
            {
                try {
                    java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
                    long msec = expiration.getTime();
                    msec += 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour.
                    expiration.setTime(msec);
                    publishProgress(arg0);

                    String existingBucketName = "nkupload";
                    String keyName = "001";
                 // String filePath = pathstring;

                    AmazonS3Client s3Client1 = new AmazonS3Client( new BasicAWSCredentials( access_key_id,secret_access_key) );
                    PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(existingBucketName,
                            keyName + ".png",new File(pictureDirectoryPath));//key is  URL

                    //making the object Public
                    por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
                    s3Client1.putObject(por);


                    String _finalUrl = "https://"+existingBucketName+".s3.amazonaws.com/" + keyName + ".png";

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // writing error to Log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast bread = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    bread.show();

                }




            }
            else
            {
                Toast bread = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                bread.show();

            }


            return null;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            System.out.println("Progress : "  + values);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            Toast bread = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            bread.show();
        }
    };


    _Task.execute((String[]) null);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i added in my Uploading function `doInBackGround`  and it works correctly and return the new path of uploaded image

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
            s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));
            PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, folderName + "/" + fileName, new File(filePath));
            s3Client.putObject(por);
            return s3Client.getResourceUrl(bucketName, folderName + "/" + fileName);
```